# Backbone.js routes don't fire correctly

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

My code is as follow:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    _data: null,
    _length: 0,
    _index: null,
    _todos: null,

    routes: {
        "*action": "index",
        "category/:name": "hashcategory"  
    },

    initialize: function(options){
        this._data = options.data;
        this._todos = new TodosCollection(options.data);
        this._length = this._todos.length;
        this._index = new CategoriesView({collection: this._todos});
    },

    index: function(){
        this._index.render();
    },

    hashcategory: function(name){
        console.log('started');
    }
});

initializeRouter = function (router) {
    Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
    $(document).on('click', 'a:not([data-bypass])', function (evt) {

        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var protocol = this.protocol + '//';

        if (href.slice(protocol.length) !== protocol) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            router.navigate(href, true);
        }
    });
    return router;
};


var start = function(){ 
    p = $.ajax({
        url: 'data/todolist.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
            var approuter = initializeRouter(new AppRouter({data: data}));
        }
    });     
};
```

I have a `<a>` link in my html which has a `href = "category/num1"` attibute. But every time I click the link, it always shows a `security error` in firebug. Actually I just have one index.html page, what I want to do is append a string to it to make a fake html page like `folder/index.html/category/num1` and all of the things will still be rendered in current page. But the url shown to me when the link is hovered is `folder/category/num1`. Because this path actually doesn't exist in my folder, I think that's why it shows a security error.

So how should I fix it? Should I create another html page and the corresponding folder? Or can I make all of the routing in one index.html page?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a `#` in the href, like

```
href = "#category/num1"
```

Comment: thx, the url is close to what I expected but the corresponding route still doesn't fire correctly.